# How do I find-and-replace all instances of a string within lines that start with another string? Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I'm trying to "quickly" convert the formatting of all arrays within my data into a nested tables. The fact I've now come here means I've failed at the "quickly" part, but it'd be useful to know - since 3-stage-find-and-replace is a recurring issue.

Basically I want to select all lines matching this criteria:

```
^t{3}\[.*
```

Find `,` within those lines

And replace with: `\] \= \{\nTTTT\["availability"\] \= "Available",\nTTT},\nTTT\[`

Is there some way to "select all" search results so that I can Find and Replace "in selection"? Or "select all marked lines"? I've tried searching through questions on here, but the specific problems people have usually mean no-one answers those exact questions but rather gives more helpful advice relating to their goal (of which I would accept, obviously, but it means those other questions don't help).

Example:

```
TT["chromas"] = {
TTT["Amethyst", "Aquamarine", "Catseye"},
```

To:

```
TT["chromas"] = {
TTT["Amethyst"] = {
TTTT["availability"] = "Available",
TTT}, 
TTT["Aquamarine"] = {
TTTT["availability"] = "Available",
TTT}, 
TTT["Catseye"] = {
TTTT["availability"] = "Available",
TTT}
TT},
```

I swapped the tabs for Ts because the platform I'm editing on does something super weird with tabs, and I could just do a mass Find+Replace for Ts after.

Comment: Please, give some sample lines and expected result.

Comment: Updated an example.

Comment: I assume the number of items in TTT are variable, ie not always 3?

Comment: That is correct.